# terminate app after opening safari - swift

Tags: ios, swift, termination

I have a button in my app that opens a link via safari. There are some tasks user does in web and finally returns to app on pressing a button in browser. what I need to do is to terminate app when safari opens so that when user comes back form browser, app inits without previous data.
That's how I open link:

```
let adrs = "mylink"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: adrs) as! URL)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you show me your link?

Comment: @Mukesh That's not an issue. suppose it's http://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can just exit the program (e.g., `exit(0)`). However, you should not do so, as iOS apps should not terminate on their own. Rather clean up your UI, e.g., remove all view controllers and create new ones.

Comment: how to clean all VCs and create new ones? and can i do it after opening the link?

Comment: You could set the `rootViewController` of the main window (save a reference to it in the App Delegate). Or set the `viewControllers` of your navigation controller, if you are using one.

Comment: can i go to root after opening url?

Comment: @HosAp Why not?

Comment: I thought codes below openURL would be ignored. that works . thanks